# Set default Color space in Xcode Interface Builder

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder, color-space

How can I set default **Color space** for InterfaceBuilder, that I don't need to check it every time?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you developing using **.xib** this can happens to you. Otherwise, Xcode remembers selecting space if you are using **.storyboards**. Simplest solution:

- Create **.storyboard** file
- Set proper **Color space**
- Delete **.storyboard** file
- Now all **.xib** files will use this new selected Color space

Comment: Can you set the default for storyboards as well?